# Setting different font color types from the same field in rule-based labeling in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, color, rule-based, font

Trying to set different font color types from the same field in rule-based labeling in QGIS.

I have a `"C°"` field with only 2 values: +56.7 C° and -89.2 C°.

Trying this expression to have it:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN "C°" = '56.7 C°' THEN '#ff0101'
    ELSE
        CASE
            WHEN "C°" = '89.2 C°' THEN '#0dff01'
        END
END
```

But as a return is all font the same:

[image]
[image].

Am I wondering if there is any solution to get different font colors for each value ?

[image]

Comment: It works fine using your expression... something else is overriding it, maybe another rule, or the expression is not evaluated at all. Please post more details about the rules/data override.

Comment: Added my rule-based window. No other expressions not executed

Comment: Do you mean 'Death Valley'?

Comment: Oh, yeah, my bad, thanks

Comment: Just as an idea: from a cartographic view, your colors are not ideal, difficult to read - especially the green color on dark yellow background. At least, consider using text buffers.

Comment: I just mess around with colors with these samples, but ok, thanks

Comment: Sorry for the nitpick, but: shouldn't it read [`56.7 °C`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celsius)?

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I fix it in my work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems unusual to have a `case when then` in the filter expression of the rule, so I am guessing you have put the expression to get the color there.

You can replace the filter to be an `ELSE` by checking the corresponding radio-box (as in the screenshot below), or to replace it with a filter such as `"C°" IS NOT NULL`.

Then, click the little epsilon sign beside the color and select `expression / edit` and enter it there.

Note that it could be simplified to

```
CASE 
WHEN  "C°"  =  '56.7 C°'   
 THEN '#ff0101'
WHEN  "C°"  =  '89.2 C°'   
 THEN '#0dff01' 
END
```

or even to a single `if else` statement.

[image]

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Since you have just two values (+56.7 C° and -89.2 C°), I would use the [if()](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#if) condition instead of the [CASE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp) statement.

```
if("C°" = '56.7 C°','#ff0101','#0dff01')
```

Comment: Thanks, it works too